# How to set my own program as a buind-in command?

Tags: freebsd

I have several perl programs and I want to let this program as a build-in command . It means I want to use `program argu1 argu2` to replace `perl program argu1 argu2` .

But I want to let this commands can only be used by me . How can I do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a directory where only you have permissions, name it "scripts"
2. Create a script file that will be named after your program
3. Add that script file to PATH in your ~/.bashrc by typing:

   ```
   PATH=$PATH:<script-directory-here>
   ```